# how to draw a functional graph using graphics 2D?

Tags: java, graphics

[image]

I create class:

```
class DrawGraph extends Jpanel{
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        for (int i = 0; i <= 600; i += 30) {
            g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(1));
            g2d.setColor(Color.GRAY);
            g2d.drawLine(i, 0, i, 600);
            g2d.drawLine(0, i, 600, i);
        }
        for (int i = 60; i < 600; i += 60) {
            if (i != 300) {
                g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2f));
                g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                g2d.drawLine(i + 1, 297, i + 1, 303);
                g2d.drawString(String.valueOf((300 - i) / 60 * -1), i - 2, 295);
                g2d.drawLine(297, i + 1, 303, i + 1);
                g2d.drawString(String.valueOf((300 - i) / 60), 303, i - 2);
            }
        }
        g2d.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g2d.drawString("y", 315, 15);
        g2d.drawString("x", 585, 285);
        g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2f));
        g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2d.drawLine(300, 0, 300, 600);
        g2d.drawLine(0, 300, 600, 300);
    }
}
```

result: [image]

But now I don't know how to continue draw Math functional to this graph. Can I use 2 class to paint in 1 panel?

Comment: *Can I use 2 class to paint in 1 panel?* - painting is done in the paintComponent() method or by invoking a method from the paintComponent() method. So if you want more functionality, then you add more functionality to the paintComponent() method. All you have done so far is paint the basic graph, If you want to paint a math function then add the logic at the bottom. Maybe add a method like: `drawMathFunction(g2d)`. In that method you add your painting logic.